# How can I view multiple files' data at once?

Tags: bash, shell

Edit: The post was closed for being a duplicate, but the best answer for me wasn't in either of those questions. using

```
head *
```

does exactly what I want

---

I have a directory that has a bunch of 1-line files in it representing some data I'd like to see. I'm wondering if there's a simple command or chain of commands I can use to get a view like

```
file1.txt
data1

file2.txt
data2

file3.txt
data3
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could open all of them in a pager like `more`:

```
more file*
```

That will look like this:

```
 $ more file*
::::::::::::::
file1
::::::::::::::
data 1
::::::::::::::
file10
::::::::::::::
data 10
::::::::::::::
file11
::::::::::::::
data 11
```

And pressing enter will load more and more files.

Alternatively, you can simply `cat file*`, but that won't have the header. You can add the header with something like this:

```
for f in file*; do echo "===== $f ====="; cat "$f"; done
```